# How can i convert multiple left join query into subquery using order by and limit?

Tags: mysql

**Query**

```
SELECT 
    a.user_name AS userName, 
    crd.mn_state_id AS mdnStateId, 
    a.alternate_number AS alternateNumber, 
    crd.temp_number AS tempMDN, 
    crd.esia_pin AS esiaPin,
    ((crd.facevalue - crd.used)/10000) AS remainingBalance, 
    a.email AS email, 
    a.created_datetime AS registrationDate, 
    hc.city_name AS homeCity, 
    cc.city_name AS currentCity, 
    crd.roaming_type AS roamingType, 
    m.expiry_datetime AS mdnExpiry, 
    a.first_name AS fullName 
FROM 
    application_users a 
LEFT JOIN 
    cards crd ON a.id = crd.application_users_id 
LEFT JOIN 
    city hc ON hc.id = crd.home_city_id  
LEFT JOIN  
    city cc ON crd.current_city_id = cc.id 
LEFT JOIN 
    mdn m ON m.fullnumber = crd.fullnumber  
ORDER BY 
    a.user_name
LIMIT 22000,1000;
```

How can I convert this query of multiple joins into subquery to get rid of filrsort?

Comment: Why do you want to change it to sub query?

Comment: I'll stick with the `LEFT JOIN` too, as it will be better extendable

Comment: i want to get rid of using file sort in extra column and i thing converting this query in subquery is better..am i right?

Comment: As using order by and limit together make problems like filesort.any solution for this?